# Xcode "Expected Delcaration","Expression not allowed at the top level" error

Tags: xcode, swift

I was trying to implement an NSDatecomponent in the viewcontroller.swift file when I got the "Expected Declaration" error and the "Instance member"something" cannot be used on type "viewcontroller"
[image]

So, then I decided to make a new .swift file and then implement the NSDatecomponents there. But then I got the "Expressions are not allowed at the top level" error.
[image]

From what I found googling, I know that I should implement this in a function, but I do not have any idea what kind of function I should wrap this into. I would also like to know why I get the errors in the viewcontroller.swift file for future reference. Thank you in advance, and sorry if my question is a duplicate.

and here is the original code

```
let weekBMondayComponents:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
weekBMondayComponents.year = 2016
weekBMondayComponents.month = 01
weekBMondayComponents.day = 11
weekBMondayComponents.hour = 08
weekBMondayComponents.minute = 39
weekBMondayComponents.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
let weekBMonday = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(weekBMondayComponents)!
```

Comment: What is your userCalendar? NSCalendar?

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers, Sorry, forgot to mention that I had this code at the top `let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to declare the weekBMondayComponents as a property or variable of the subclass, and initialize it perhaps in the viewDidLoad notification handler.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var weekBMondayComponents:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

func setUpADay() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    weekBMondayComponents.year = 2016
    weekBMondayComponents.month = 01
    weekBMondayComponents.day = 11
    weekBMondayComponents.hour = 08
    weekBMondayComponents.minute = 39
    weekBMondayComponents.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
}
```